# How to store Day in MySQL and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am required to store DayId in my database. This is what I have so far (not sure if this is a good approach to store a day type)

```
public enum DayType {

    MONDAY(1),TUESDAY(2),WEDNESDAY(3),THURSDAY(4),FRIDAY(5),SATURDAY(6),SUNDAY(7);
```

The entity uses it is **AppointmentSlot.java**

```
public class AppointmentSlot{

        ...

        @Column
        @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        private DayType dayId;
        ...
}
```

I set the dayID before persisting it with `appointmentSlot.setDayId(DayType.MONDAY);`. However in my database I notice the stored value in `dayId` column is 0. Why didn't it stored as 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the `EnumType.ORDINAL` javadoc

> Persist enumerated type property or field as an integer.

This means it uses the `ordinal()` value of the `enum` to store in the database. This usually has to do with the position of the `enum` in the list. `MONDAY` is first so its `ordinal()` is 0.

I don't know of a straight way to have Hibernate map the custom field of your custom `enum` to the table. **However, there is no point doing that. Hibernate will be able to map back and forth using the `ordinal()` or the `String` value of the `enum`.** They are constants after all.

Comment: Noted. By the way, should I change my numbering from 0 to 6 ?

Comment: @abiieez That's up to you and how you use it in your application. It's irrelevant to Hibernate.

Comment: As a bit of additional information, EnumType.ORDINAL is not very human reader-friendly when storing in a DB, and also is very risky to use in situations where the enum order in the file might potentially change.  This probably doesn't really apply in this situation as the days in a week are "generally" fixed (though some people prefer to start their week numbering on Monday while others prefer to start with the traditional Sunday, and I've seen many other schemes).  Something to be aware of

Answer (score 2):

Becasue, `EnumType.ORDINAL` start from 0. You can also define as `EnumType.String`.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer having a separate table holding the DayType enum values (along another new entity that maps to this table). The AppointmentSlot entity will then have a foreign key to the DayType entity id. Any insert or updates to an instance of the AppointmentSlot would require you to fetch the DayType value (required id) beforehand, ensuring consistency between your code and db.